# static_assert compile-time argument check with C++20 concept

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, static-assert

I'm coding a function that evaluates binomial coefficients: `binom(N, K)`

I want to check that both N and K are unsigned-type integers with N >= K at compile time,
but having a problem with this.

Here's my code:

```
template <typename N>
concept Unsigned = std::is_unsigned_v<N>;

template <Unsigned U>
constexpr double binom(U N, U K) {
    static_assert(N >= K);
    double d = 1.0;
    while (K) {
        d *= static_cast<double>(N) / static_cast<double>(K);
        K--;
        N--;
    }
    return d;
}

template <Unsigned U>
constexpr double binom_pmf(U N, U K, double theta) {
    return binom(N, K) * std::pow(theta, K) * std::pow(1 - theta, N - K);
}
```

Here is the error message from Clang 10:

```
/mnt/c/programming/ML/2_3_1_binomial_bernoulli.cpp:12:19: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(N >= K);
                  ^~~~~~
/mnt/c/programming/ML/2_3_1_binomial_bernoulli.cpp:24:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'binom<unsigned long>' requested here
    return binom(N, K) * std::pow(theta, K) * std::pow(1 - theta, N - K);
           ^
/mnt/c/programming/ML/2_3_1_binomial_bernoulli.cpp:36:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'binom_pmf<unsigned long>' requested here
        y[K] = binom_pmf(N, K, theta);
```

The problem is `static_assert(N >= K)`.

I've declared parameter N as `constexpr size_t`, and K is the loop parameter in `for (size_t K = 0; K <= N; K++)`, so anyone can conclude that N and K are surely unsigned integers with N >= K, but the compiler doesn't look so happy.

Oh, the compiler is also complaining when I try to insert `static_assert(theta >= 0.0 && theta <= 1.0);` in `binom_pdf`.

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters are not `constexpr`.

`template <Unsigned U, U N, U K>
constexpr double binom()` would allow your `static_assert`.

Comment: Thank you very much! But my attempt to ````template <Unsigned U, U N, U K, double theta>
constexpr double binom_pmf() {```` is still failing. How can I pass floating-point types as template parameters?

Comment: `double` cannot be template parameter (at least in C++17). C++20 should allow that though (see [template_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)). C++20 is not fully supported by compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are happy with all these being available only for constant expressions, declare the functions `consteval` and `throw` (no actual exception needed) when you don’t like the arguments.  That allows floating-point types even without compiler support for them as template parameters.