# How to implement std::lcm to be standard conform?

Tags: c++, constant-expression, lcm, c++23

I'm trying to implement std::lcm and I need to `static_assert` that the arguments or result are within bounds as required by the standard:

> The behavior is undefined if |m|, |n|, or the least common multiple of |m| and |n| is not representable as a value of type std::common_type_t<M, N>.

Simplified the problem is this: Say I have the following code:

```
constexpr void foo(int x) noexcept {
    if consteval {
        static_assert(x == 0, "x must be 0");
    }
}
```

Compiling a c++23 gives:

```
<source>: In function 'costexpr void foo(int) noexcept':
<source>:3:25: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    3 |         static_assert(x == 0, "x must be 0");
      |                       ~~^~~~
<source>:3:25: error: 'x' is not a constant expression
```

How do I static_assert that x == 0? Or something equivalent that shows the message on error.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Will consteval allow using static_assert on function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57226797/12122460) as noexcept can't throw.

This is not a duplicate of [static_assert compile-time argument check with C++20 concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949215/static-assert-compile-time-argument-check-with-c20-concept) because the use case (implementing std::lcm) does not allow template arguments.

This is not a duplicate of [How to tell static_assert that constexpr function arguments are const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789913/how-to-tell-static-assert-that-constexpr-function-arguments-are-const), same reason.

Comment: Perhaps use `if (...) throw (...)` anyway [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9TTW38MhT)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That gives a hard to read error message: https://godbolt.org/z/8sbWba375 When I did this in `lcm` gcc always warned about the throw because noexcept means throw terminates.

Comment: You can't `static_assert` on the runtime value of a variable. The standard doesn't require an error, it says that the behaviour is undefined, therefore you can do whatever you like when an out of range argument is passed. You can throw an exception, return the wrong answer, call `std::terminate` or anything else you like

Comment: @AlanBirtles Except a constexpr must not have UB. So no, you can't do just anything.

Comment: E.g libc++ [aborts](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/36c7d79dc4c114728b5f003bf48cd7a41bf932a4/libcxx/include/__numeric/gcd_lcm.h#L75) if the result is out of range

Comment: @AlanBirtles How is `_LIBCPP_ASSERT` defined? Anything that could be ported to gcc?

Comment: `static_assert` make sense just at compile time evaluation, so are you asking for a way to ignore it when `foo()` is called in a non-constexpr context (runtime)?

Comment: @MatG No. `if consteval` already does that. The error happens when it's a const evaluation.

Comment: "hard to read error message" In my day we had to wade through pages and pages of template instantiation errors (in the snow uphill both ways). The message there is quite passable. "gcc always warned about the throw" Then perhaps you should show your real code and ask a question about that.

Comment: Think it just does `std::abort` https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html

Comment: Libstdc++ [just returns the wrong answer](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/58b67140de7685de25b2f5775b5735f9c491b058/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/numeric#L147)

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's the bit I want to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can manage is this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr int foo(int x) noexcept {
    if consteval {
        if (x !=0) {
            std::abort(); // "x must be 0"
        }
    }
    return x;
}

constinit int x = foo(1);
constinit int y = foo(0);
```

This generates the lengthy error output:

```
<source>:12:15: error: variable does not have a constant initializer
constinit int x = foo(1);
              ^   ~~~~~~
<source>:12:1: note: required by 'constinit' specifier here
constinit int x = foo(1);
^~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:13: note: non-constexpr function 'abort' cannot be used in a constant expression
            std::abort(); // "x must be 0"
            ^
<source>:12:19: note: in call to 'foo(1)'
constinit int x = foo(1);
                  ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:591:13: note: declared here
extern void abort (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
            ^
```

The `"x must be 0"` is pretty hidden, which I'm not happy about.

Comment: Why not just simply [`assert(x == 0 && "x must be 0")`](https://godbolt.org/z/eb44rMnjh)?

Comment: Because of `#ifdef NDEBUG`